# Design pattern to handle the interaction between different types of objects

Tags: java, c#, oop, design-patterns, software-design

I have a C# program that has a class called `Ball` that has two `enum` fields called `BallColor` and `BallType`. There are 7 ball colors (red, blue, yellow, etc.) and 7 ball types (tennis, soccer, bowling, etc.). A ball object can have any of the possible combinations of color and type.

In my program, I have many `Ball` objects of different color and type combinations. Balls can interact with each other via collisions. When two balls collide, it triggers an interaction that is handled by a function called `handleInteraction(ball1, ball2)`. The interaction between the two balls depends on the type and color of each ball. For example, if any bowling ball hits any ping pong ball, the ping pong is destroyed and the bowling ball continues to move with its original velocity. However, if any soccer ball collides with a bowling ball, the soccer ball bounces off the bowling ball and the bowling ball's velocity is reduced by `n`. Another example, if a red tennis ball collides with a green ping pong ball, the ping pong ball bounces off the tennis ball and the color of the ping pong ball is changed to the same color of the tennis ball (red).

In my `handleInteraction(ball1, ball2)` function, I've been handling the interactions using nested `switch` statements. However, as I write more code to handle all of the scenarios, nested `switch` statements doesn't seem to be the right approach.

Can anyone think of a better way to handle the interaction between balls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to create interface for Interaction result and for ball:

```
public interface IInteractionResult
{
    void Handle();
}

public interface IBall
{
    BallTypeEnum BallType { get; }

    IInteractionResult HandleInteraction(IBall ball);
}
```

And implement every of your possible classes which implements `IInteractionResult` where the logic for interaction provided at `Handle` method:

```
public class DestroyInteractionResult : IInteractionResult
{

    public void Handle()
    {
        //your code for destroy result behaviour
    }
}

public class BounceInteractionResult : IInteractionResult
{

    public void Handle()
    {
        //your code for bounce result behaviour
    }
}

public class NothingInteractionResult : IInteractionResult
{

    public void Handle()
    {
        //your code for nothing
    }
}
```

After this implement your classes for `Ball` which will implement `IBall` with `switch` statement at implementation of `HandleInteraction`. `SoccerBall` for example:

```
public class SoccerBall : IBall
{
    public BallTypeEnum BallType
    {
        get { return BallTypeEnum.Soccer; }
    }

    public IInteractionResult HandleInteraction(IBall ball)
    {
        switch (ball.BallType)
        {
            case BallTypeEnum.Soccer:
                return new BounceInteractionResult();
            case BallTypeEnum.Bowl:
                return new DestroyInteractionResult();
            case BallTypeEnum.PingPong:
                return new BounceInteractionResult();
            // and so on
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException("Undefined ball type");
    }
}
```

Separate classes for each ball type and for each interaction helps you to collect single logic for each type into single class.

And you `handleInteraction` would look like:

```
public void handleInteraction(IBall ball1, IBall ball2)
{
    var interaction = ball1.HandleInteraction(ball2);

    interaction.Handle();
}
```

In my opinion it is most flexible solution. Some kind of Strategy pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, specifically the suggestion of the Strategy pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The better approach is to Have some more property in the Ball Class like below. More like Actual Physics

```
prop double Mass { get; set;)
```

Inside handleInteraction

```
If(b1.Mass / b2.Mass < 0.1) // Make your Own ratios
    //Destrioy Ball
else if(..)
    //Move in derecton or Bounce
```

My approach is, make properties for all behaviors

Answer (score 0):

Consider abstracting the notion of a collision. There's a rule about velocities, colors, etc. Put those rules in a table, and just do a lookup and apply them.

> For example, if any bowling ball hits any ping pong ball, the ping pong is destroyed and the bowling ball continues to move with its original velocity.

A ball can be destroyed (or not) after a collision. (boolean value)

> However, if any soccer ball collides with a bowling ball, the soccer ball bounces off the bowling ball and the bowling ball's velocity is reduced by n.

A ball's velocity is reduced by n.

A ball can change direction ("bounces off of").

> Another example, if a red tennis ball collides with a green ping pong ball, the ping pong ball bounces off the tennis ball and the color of the ping pong ball is changed to the same color of the tennis ball (red).

A ball can change color.

In these examples, there are 4 dimensions of rules. If you're pretty sure of that model, you can easily code something to define the rules for each collision (in a table or map) and apply the rules without a lot of conditions.